# Inserting DB name into Sqlite3 command

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm using python 2.7.3 and Sqlite3 to save some data in a small db. I have the following sql command:

```
thedb = "allpeople"
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" % (thedb, data))
conn.commit()
```

But its throwing the following error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: At the very least, you should put a `%r` instead of `%s`, or you're gonna have problems if the table name contains special characters.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert the *table* name (not the database). You appear to be mixing that up with SQL parameters; string templating and providing SQL parameters for your query are two entirely separate operations.

You'd have to use string formatting *separately* to build the query string:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" % thedb, data)
```

or perhaps a little clearer to illustrate what is going on:

```
query = "INSERT INTO %s VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" % thedb
cursor.execute(query, data)
```

Note that this opens you up to a possible SQL injection vector. Perhaps you should look into a decent SQL library instead; SQLAlchemy lets you build SQL queries from Python calls (among other tasks).